# How to set break point in AOSP?

Tags: android

I am not sure if it is doable. I am building AOSP, and would like to set break point some of the framework files. [ eg: ServiceManager.java],  It is possible to do?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to setup breakpoints in Android framework services. Most of the framework services (the Java ones) are hosted in a Linux process called system_server. It is possible to debug Java code in this process if you setup your eclipse project right.

Please check [Debugging Android Framework services](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.com/2014/06/debugging-android-java-framework.html) link. The key thing is you need to setup your eclipse project right. The link has step by step tutorial on how to do this with examples.